# Return a char* or use memcpy?

Tags: c, http

I'm trying to write a function that generates the header of HTTP requests. I currently have something like

```
static char* genHeader() { 
    return("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n\
            Host: www.example.com\r\n\
            Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"); 
}
```

I'm aware that it could also be done by:

```
static void genHeader(char *header) { memcpy(header, ...); }
```

Which one is closer to the "canonical" way of generating a header? In the second method, I'd need to free the memory whereas in the first I wouldn't, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method is better, if the string is not going to change or have some fields to be filled by the function, then the first method is much easier to implement, having to keep track of memory allocated on the heap is always difficult, it's not necessary to do it in your case, you can even use a macro, like

```
#define HTTP_HEADER \
    "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n" \
    "Host: www.example.com\r\n" \
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"
```

instead of the function.

A situation where you need to dynamically generate the header, for example because the `Host` changes, would **require** the second solution, since you would need to allocate enough space for the header, and then build up the header string.

And in that case it would be better if the function takes care of returning the pointer to the newly allocated and build string, but yes, the caller shall be responsible of calling `free()`.

Also, there is absolutely no need for parentheses in your `return` statement, it makes the code hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the right question as your example generates a header that's a literal. In real life I assume it will have dynamic content. The question is the about how to generate dynamic string content. To generate variable size and content strings you will need to allocate it on the heap (unless you want to do really hard work with static memory pools ). This suggests you need

```
static char * MakeHeader(...);
```

and tell the caller to free the result when done.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for a function to produce a string:

- Return a pointer to a static one, as in your first example. This is simple and requires no memory management, but the content of the string has to be known at compile time.
- Copy the string into a buffer supplied by the caller, as `sprintf()` does for example:

  ```
  void genHeader(char* buffer, size_t length);
  ```

  This would write characters into `buffer` until `length` is reached. It makes `genHeader()` simpler by forcing the caller to allocate memory. However, it might not be possible to know in advance how much memory to allocate, in which case the caller will either allocate too much or too little. You could have `genHeader()` return the size of the buffer requires if `buffer` is null, or some variation.
- Allocate the string yourself:

  ```
  char* genHeader();
  ```

  This avoids most of the problems above by giving you complete control over the process of allocating enough memory to hold the content. However, the caller is now forced to free the memory.

I would go with the third option for any kind of dynamic content.